# How to change stacking order for java applet

Tags: html, css, web

I'm building a web site that has a simple applet for fading images. Looks great except when viewing on smaller screen resolution. The images sit on top of other elements of the page. How do I force the applet behind these elements. Static images are fine. I have tried using the z-index and overflow properties to no avail. Please help!

Thanks in advance